# How do I return the functionality to my main method?

Tags: java

I had a working program all in one class but I thought that it would be better to separate the classes so I split my program into three .java files and now the program is no longer running. I do not have a single error anywhere in the program but when I try run the program I get this error message

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Tetris.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:125)"
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

These are my three files:

**Tetris.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import static java.awt.Color.*;


public class Tetris extends Applet {

    //
    // STATIC MEMBERS
    //

    private final static int INITIAL_DELAY = 1000;

    public final static byte ROWS = 20;
    public final static byte COLUMNS = 10;
    public final static int EMPTY = -1;

    static Color[] colors =
            {black, green, blue, red,
                    yellow, magenta, pink, cyan};




    private final static Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.black;


    public final static boolean PIECE_BITS[][][] = {

            {
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
                    {false, false, true, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, false, true, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
                    {false, true, false, false},
            },
            {
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, false, false, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
                    {false, true, true, false},
            },
    };

    private static Random random = new Random();

    //
    // INSTANCE DATA
    //

    public static int grid[][] = new int[ROWS][COLUMNS];
    public static Timer timer;

    private int next_piece_grid[][] = new int[4][4];
    private GridCanvas game_grid = new GridCanvas(grid, true);
    private GridCanvas next_piece_canvas = new GridCanvas(next_piece_grid, false);
    private TetrisPiece cur_piece;
    private TetrisPiece next_piece = randomPiece();


    //
    // INNER CLASSES
    //


    private class Timer extends Thread {
        private long m_delay;
        private boolean m_paused = true;
        private boolean m_fast = false;
        private ActionListener m_cb;

        public Timer(long delay, ActionListener cb) {
            setDelay(delay);
            m_cb = cb;
        }

        public void setPaused(boolean pause) {
            m_paused = pause;
            if (m_paused) {

            } else {

                synchronized (this) {
                    this.notify();
                }
            }
        }

        public void setDelay(long delay) {
            m_delay = delay;
        }

        public void setFast(boolean fast) {
            m_fast = fast;
            if (m_fast) {
                try {
                    this.checkAccess();
                    this.interrupt(); // no exception, so OK to interrupt
                } catch (SecurityException se) {
                }
            }
        }


        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    sleep(m_fast ? 30 : m_delay);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                if (m_paused) {
                    try {
                        synchronized (this) {
                            this.wait();
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    }
                }
                synchronized (this) {
                    m_cb.actionPerformed(null);
                }
            }
        }
    } // end class Timer

    private class GridCanvas extends DoubleBufferedCanvas {
        private int grid[][];

        public GridCanvas(int[][] grid, boolean do_background) {
            this.grid = grid;
            clear();
        }

        private void clear() {
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++)
                    grid[i][j] = EMPTY;
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(grid[0].length * 30, grid.length * 30);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            g = this.startPaint(g); // returned g paints into offscreen image
            int width = this.getSize().width;
            int height = this.getSize().height;
            g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            int cell_size, xstart, ystart;
            double panel_aspect_ratio = (double) width / height;
            double grid_aspect_ratio = (double) grid[0].length / grid.length;
            if (panel_aspect_ratio > grid_aspect_ratio) {
                // extra space on sides
                cell_size = (int) ((double) height / grid.length + 0.5);
                xstart = (int) (width / 2 - (grid[0].length / 2.0 * cell_size + 0.5));
                ystart = 0;
            } else {
                // extra vertical space
                cell_size = (int) ((double) width / grid[0].length + 0.5);
                xstart = 0;
                ystart = (int) (height / 2 - (grid.length / 2.0 * cell_size + 0.5));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
                    if (grid[i][j] != EMPTY) {
                        g.setColor(colors[grid[i][j]]);
                        int x = xstart + j * cell_size;
                        int y = ystart + i * cell_size;
                        g.fill3DRect(x, y, cell_size, cell_size, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            this.endPaint(); // paints accumulated image in one shot
        }
    }

    private TetrisPiece randomPiece() {
        int rand = Math.abs(random.nextInt());
        return new TetrisPiece(rand % (colors.length));
    }

    private void installNewPiece() {
        next_piece_canvas.clear();
        cur_piece = next_piece;
        cur_piece.setPosition(3, -4); //-4 to start above top of grid
        if (cur_piece.canPaste()) {
            next_piece = randomPiece();
            next_piece.setPosition(0, 0);
            next_piece.paste(next_piece_grid);
            next_piece_canvas.repaint();
        } else
            gameOver();
    }

    private void gameOver() {
        System.out.println("Game Over!");
        timer.setPaused(true);
    }



    public void start() {
        timer = new Timer(INITIAL_DELAY, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                synchronized (timer) {
                    if (cur_piece.canStepDown()) {
                        cur_piece.cut();
                        cur_piece.stepDown();
                        cur_piece.paste();
                    } else { // it hit something
                        timer.setFast(false);
                        if (!cur_piece.isTotallyOnGrid())
                            gameOver();
                        else {
                            installNewPiece();
                        }
                    }
                }
                game_grid.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        pauseGame();
        synchronized (timer) {
            timer.stop();
        }
        timer = null;
    }

    public void startGame() {
        timer.setDelay(INITIAL_DELAY);
        timer.setPaused(false);
    }


    private void pauseGame() {
        timer.setPaused(true);
    }


    public void init() {
        installNewPiece();

        //create key listener for moving left, moving right

        class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

                switch (keycode) {
                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                        if (e.getKeyCode() == 37 || e.getKeyCode() == 38) {
                            int dir = e.getKeyCode() == 37 ? -1 : 1;
                            synchronized (timer) {
                                cur_piece.cut();
                                cur_piece.setX(cur_piece.getX() + dir);

                                if (!cur_piece.canPaste()) {
                                    cur_piece.setX(cur_piece.getX() - dir);
                                }
                            }
                        }


                }
            }
        }


        //setting background colour and Tetrus grid
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        this.add(game_grid);
        this.setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
        this.validate();
    }

    public int[][] getGrid () {
        return grid;
    }


    class DoubleBufferedCanvas extends Canvas {
        private Image mActiveOffscreenImage = null;
        private Dimension mOffscreenSize = new Dimension(-1, -1);
        private Graphics mActiveOffscreenGraphics = null;
        private Graphics mSystemGraphics = null;

        DoubleBufferedCanvas() {

        }

        public void update(Graphics g) {
            paint(g);
        }

        public Graphics startPaint(Graphics sysgraph) {
            mSystemGraphics = sysgraph;
            Dimension d = getSize();
            if ((mActiveOffscreenImage == null) ||
                    (d.width != mOffscreenSize.width) ||
                    (d.height != mOffscreenSize.height)) {
                mActiveOffscreenImage = createImage(d.width, d.height);
                mActiveOffscreenGraphics = mActiveOffscreenImage.getGraphics();
                mOffscreenSize = d;
                mActiveOffscreenGraphics.setFont(getFont());
            }

            return mActiveOffscreenGraphics;
        }

        public void endPaint() {

            mSystemGraphics.drawImage(mActiveOffscreenImage, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**TetrisPiece.java**

```
import java.awt.*; 

    private boolean squares[][];
    private int type;
    private Point position = new Point(3, -4); // -4 to start above top row
    public int getX() { return position.x; }
    public int getY() { return position.y; }
    public void setX(int newx) { position.x = newx; }
    public void setY(int newy) { position.y = newy; }
    public void setPosition(int newx, int newy) { setX(newx); setY(newy);


    }

    public TetrisPiece(int type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.squares = new boolean[4][4];
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                this.squares[i][j] = Tetris.PIECE_BITS[type][i][j];
    }

    public boolean canStepDown() {
        synchronized(Tetris.timer) {
            cut();
            position.y++;
            boolean OK = canPaste();
            position.y--;
            paste();
            return OK;
        }
    }

    public boolean canPaste() {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                int to_x = j + position.x;
                int to_y = i + position.y;
                if(squares[i][j]) {

                    //checks if sqaure is too far left or right

                    if(0 > to_x || to_x >= Tetris.COLUMNS
                            || to_y >= Tetris.ROWS) // square off bottom?
                    {
                        return false;

                        // This allows the user to move a piece before it drops
                        // completely into view.
                    }
                    if(to_y >= 0 && Tetris.grid[to_y][to_x] != Tetris.EMPTY)
                        return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void stepDown() {
        position.y++;
    }

    public void cut() {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                if(squares[i][j] && position.y+i>=0)
                    Tetris.grid[position.y + i][position.x + j] = Tetris.EMPTY;
    }

    /**
     * Paste the color info of this piece into the given grid
     */
    public void paste(int into[][]) {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                if(squares[i][j] && position.y+i>=0)
                    into[position.y + i][position.x + j] = type;
    }

    /**
     * No argument version assumes pasting into main game grid
     */
    public void paste() {
        paste(Tetris.grid);
    }

    // this method is a bit of a hack to check for the case
    // where a piece may be safely on the grid but have one or more
    // rows of empty squares that are above the grid and therefore OK
    public boolean isTotallyOnGrid() {
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            if(position.y + i >= 0)
                return true; //everything from here down is on grid
            // this row is above grid so look for non-empty squares
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
                if(squares[i][j])
                    return false;
        }
        System.err.println("TetrisPiece.isTotallyOnGrid internal error");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**TetrisMain.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;


public class TetrisMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Frame frame = new Frame("Tetris");
        Tetris tetris = new Tetris();
        frame.add(tetris);
        tetris.init();
        tetris.start();
        tetris.startGame();

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.setSize(250,500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you running it

Comment: You have to run `TetrisMain` not `Tetris`

Comment: go to 'run/debug configuration' and change your Main class.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are trying to run in an IDE from the `Tetris` class, which is why it's looking for your `main()` (the "entry point" to your program) method there. i.e.

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Tetris.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

You've moved your `main()` method to `TetrisMain` so you need to run it from there